# Friction acting as an internal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, work

I was solving this problem in my assignment:

[image]

Assuming a frictional force  **F** acts on the block of mass *m*, a force **-F** will act on plank of mass *M*. Hence, the net work done by frictional force should be zero, as friction is an internal force , but option D is given incorrect. What's the error in my reasoning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: > *"as friction is an internal force"* Internal forces can work and often do work. Consider forces that make your arms move. They increase their kinetic energy, so they do work. And they are internal to your body, there is no need for an external force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the unit vector $\hat i$ points to the right in your diagram, the bottom block is on a frictionless surface, block $M$ starts from rest and block $m$ has an initial velocity $v_{\rm i} \,\hat i$.

The magnitude of the frictional force on both blocks is $F$ and their directions are opposite (Newton's third law).

The acceleration of block $m$ is $-\frac Fm \,\hat i$ and that of block $M$ is $+\frac FM \,\hat i$.

As there are no horizontal external forces on the two block system then the momentum of the two block system is conserved.
The final velocity of the two blocks is $\frac{m}{M+m}v_{\rm i}\, \hat i$.

The velocity-time graphs for the two blocks are shown below.

[image]

The area under a velocity-time graph is the displacement and from the graph it is clear that the displacement of mass $m$ is greater than that of mass $M$.
So although both frictional forces have the same magnitude the frictional force acting on mass $m$ does more work, $\int \vec F \cdot d\vec x$, than the frictional force acting on mass $M$.

The work done on mass $m$ is negative because the frictional force and the displacement are in opposite directions and the work done on mass $M$ is positive because the frictional force and the displacement are in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

Work is given by $$W=\int\mathbf F \cdot \text d \mathbf x$$ which, in the case of constant forces in 1D reduces to $$W=F\Delta x$$This definition depends on the path over which the force is applied, so having equal forces is not a sufficient condition to have the total work done on both blocks by friction be $0$.

I would consider how far each object moves relative to the chosen reference frame, and, assuming the friction force is constant, you should see what the answer is fairly easily.

Comment: Here, according to my knowledge, dx is displacement of point of application of the force, which depends on the relative displacement of the block  w.r.t plank or vice-versa. So shouldn't the "dx" term be equal for both the forces ?

Comment: @user204843 You take the path each object takes, and then you integrate over that path. If each object experiences the same force, then the only way to have the same work is for the objects to move the same distance (in 1D). Do they move the same distance while there is slipping?

Comment: @user204843 You do not look at this displacement of the point of contact. You look at the displacement of each object. Work doesn't care about what is touching where. It just depends on the forces acting on the object and the path that object takes.

Comment: @aaraon Stevens  No, they move different distances!  and I got your point , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The inner actions have a zero resultant but the associated power can be non-zero when there is slipping.

We have in general $\overrightarrow{{{F}_{1\to 2}}}=-\overrightarrow{{{F}_{2\to 1}}}$ but $P=\overrightarrow{{{F}_{1\to 2}}}\centerdot \overrightarrow{{{v}_{2}}}+\overrightarrow{{{F}_{2\to 1}}}\centerdot \overrightarrow{{{v}_{1}}}=\overrightarrow{{{F}_{1\to 2}}}\centerdot \left( \overrightarrow{{{v}_{2}}}-\overrightarrow{{{v}_{1}}} \right)=\overrightarrow{{{F}_{1\to 2}}}\centerdot \overrightarrow{{{v}_{g}}}$ with $\overrightarrow{{{v}_{g}}}$ the sliding velocity.
Sorry for my english !

Answer (score 0):

For the free body system we can write this equations:

$$m\,\ddot{x}_m+F_\mu=0$$
$$\dot{x}_m=-\frac{F_\mu}{m}\,t+v_0\tag 1$$
$$M\,\ddot{x}_M-F_\mu=0$$
$$\dot{x}_M=\frac{F_\mu}{M}\,t$$

Where $F_\mu$ the friction force between the block and the plank.

the friction force work is:

$W=\int \,F_\mu\, dx=\int_0^{t_s}\,\,F_\mu\,\frac{dx}{dt}\,dt$

$t_s$ is the time that take the mass $m$ to reach the end of the block.

$\Rightarrow$

$$W_m=F_\mu\int_0^{t_s}\left(\,-\frac{F_\mu}{m}\,t+v_0\right)\,dt=F_\mu\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{F_\mu\,t_s^2}{m}+v_0\,t_s\right)\tag 2$$

and

$$W_M=F_\mu\,\int_0^{t_s}\,\left(\frac{F_\mu}{M}\,t\right)\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\frac{F_\mu^2\,t_s^2}{M}\tag 3$$

with equation (1) and the velocity $v_s$ that the mass $m$ reach at time $t_s$ we can calculate the final time:

$v_s=-\frac{F_\mu}{m}\,t_s+v_0\quad \Rightarrow$

$$t_s=\frac{m}{F_\mu}\,\left(v_0-v_s\right)\tag 4$$

with equation (4) in (2) and (3) we obtain for $W_m$

$$W_m=\frac{1}{2}\,m\left(v_0^2-v_s^2\right)\quad, v_0 > v_s \Rightarrow\quad W_m > 0$$

and for $W_M$

$$W_M=\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{\left(v_0-v_s\right)^2\,m^2}{M}> 0$$

**so both work done by the friction force are positive**!